# How to execute an SQL query based on results of another query

Tags: sql, mysql

I have an SQL query that returns a column of values, e.g.:

```
     id |
1 val01 |
2 val02 |
...
```

Now I want to write another query that will use the values from the first query above and execute multiple times while having the results of each query in a separate column, e.g.:

```
     column1 | column2(based on val1) | column3(based on val2) | ...
staticValue1 |                        |                        |
staticValue1 |                        |                        |
..
```

The idea is to to it as single query.
Also, the number of results of the initial query will vary.

Comment: No SQL query can have a variable number of columns depending on the values it reads during execution. Columns must be fixed in the select-list at the time the query is parsed, i.e. before it begins reading data. You cannot do what you describe in a single query.

Comment: @BillKarwin Thank you for your comment. Perhaps a different approach is applicable? Say use the first query as a part of the select statement of the second query and thus define the resulting columns? Thanks.

Comment: You can query first to get a list of the distinct `val01`, `val02`, etc. Then use that result in your client application to format a second query with one column for each of the vals.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT *
FROM your_second_table
WHERE column_name IN (SELECT id FROM your_first_table);

Replace your_second_table, column_name, and your_first_table with your actual table names and column names. This query will return rows from your_second_table where the value in column_name matches any of the values returned by the subquery.